# How many draws to collect all items?

Tags: probability, expectation

Let's say there's  a box with ***n*** different items in it and the goal is to collect all different items. This is done by drawing a random item with probability of 1/***n***, writing the outcome and putting the item back in the box. What is the expected number of drawing that will be made?

Comment: Similar to this question, which also has no answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227556/the-exact-probability-of-observing-x-unique-elements-after-sampling-with-repla

Comment: Check out this one: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30483/probability-of-selecting-each-item-at-least-once-when-sampling-with-replacement