# How to calculate the sum of a finite series: $P(k) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} S_2(m,i) \frac{n!}{n^m (n-i)!}$?

Tags: probability, permutations, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers

I would like to calculate  $P(k) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} S_2(m,i) \frac{n!}{n^m  (n-i)!}$ where $S_2(m,i)$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Asymptotic_approximation).

This problem is formulated from the question: uniformly draw $m$ samples with replacement from a set consists of $n$ unique elements, what is the probability that we get at most $k$ unique samples in the drawn $m$ samples?

The probelm is already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227556/the-exact-probability-of-observing-x-unique-elements-after-sampling-with-repla?rq=1) but I am interesting in if it could be simplified, or can we get a lower bound of the probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability you wrote is related to the development of powers into [Falling Factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)
$$
n^{\,m}  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,i\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {S_2 (m,i){{n!} \over {\left( {n - i} \right)!}}}  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,i\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\left\{ \matrix{
  m \cr 
  i \cr}  \right\}n^{\,\underline {\,i\,} } } 
$$
or
$$
x^{\,m}  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,i\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\left\{ \matrix{
  m \cr 
  i \cr}  \right\}x^{\,\underline {\,i\,} } } 
$$
where the curly brackets is another conventional way to write the Stirling N. of 2nd kind.

The Stirling N. (and falling factorials) satisfy many interesting relations, but as far as I am aware, none of them
is useful to express  the partial sum of the above expansion of $x^m$ into
a form "closer" than the sum itself.