# What is probability that a sample covers all classes?

Tags: probability

Suppose:

1. there are $n$ distinct classes in a population (i.e. each member of
   the population is a member of exactly one class),
2. (For simplicity) the classes are all equally sized and
   the probability of selecting (with replacement) a  member from
   any one class is $1/n$.
3. $x$ samples
   are taken (with replacement) where $x \ge n$.

What is the probability $p(x,n)$ that each class is represented by at least one of the samples?

What I've tried: special case
$$p(n,n) = \frac{n!}{n^n}.$$
e.g.
$$p(6,6) = \frac{6!}{6^6} = \frac{6}{6} \times \frac{5}{6} \times ... \times \frac{2}{6} \times \frac{1}{6}.$$

The 6 distinct classes could be the faces 1,2, .. , 6 on a fair die. $p(6,6)$ is the probability that when the die is rolled 6 times, no faces come up twice. Any face is OK for the first roll, then 5 faces, then 4, ...

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32800/probability-distribution-of-coverage-of-a-set-after-x-independently-randomly ?

Comment: See also the [Coupon Collector's Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) for a related problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking question as answered. Thank you