# The probability that the size of a set is N after observing M unique elements from a sample of X (with replacement)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Problem**

Given a set of unknown size, *X* elements are sampled with replacement. Of these sampled elements, *M* elements are unique, meaning (*X* - *M*) elements were chosen more than once. Knowing this, what is the probability that the set has size *N*?

**Related question on SE**

If a set has *n* elements and *x* elements are selected with replacement, what is the probability that *m* unique elements are selected? [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32800/probability-distribution-of-coverage-of-a-set-after-x-independently-randomly/32816#32816)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We require the probability $\operatorname{Pr}\left(N = n\middle| M = m\right)$ after observing $m$ unique elements sampled from a sample size of $X$. By Bayes' theorem (where $X$ has been suppressed in the notation):
$$ \operatorname{Pr}\left(N = n\middle| M = m\right) = \dfrac{\operatorname{Pr}\left( M = m\middle|N = n\right)\operatorname{Pr}\left(N = n\right)}{\operatorname{Pr}\left( M = m\right)}$$
From this it appears that the problem is ill-defined without knowledge of the prior distribution $\operatorname{Pr}\left(N = n\right)$. However if we proceed with the mindset that '$N$ is equally likely to be anything' (in the positive integers), then we could choose the [improper prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability#Improper_priors) that $\operatorname{Pr}\left(N = n\right) \propto 1$. This allows us to take
$$ \operatorname{Pr}\left(N = n\middle| M = m\right) \propto \operatorname{Pr}\left( M = m\middle|N = n\right) $$
where the right-hand side is the same probability as from the related question. Hence this expresses that the desired probability is proportional to the likelihood, and we can obtain a valid figure for the probability through normalisation:
$$ \operatorname{Pr}\left(N = n\middle| M = m\right) = \dfrac{\operatorname{Pr}\left( M = m\middle|N = n\right)}{\sum_{i = m}^{\infty}\operatorname{Pr}\left( M = m\middle|N = i\right)} $$